# Was it common to use the noun mem-sahib outside India?

Tags: etymology, nouns, word-usage, commonweath-english, hindi

I have recently seen the noun *[mem-sahib](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mem-sahib)*, used to refer a white foreign woman living in India, in two different books. The books are *Indian Passion* and *Nowhere in Africa*.

I have not found any information about the use of *mem-sahib* in other countries, but in the latest book, I have seen this word many times even though the story happens in Kenya. If *mem-sahib* comes from a mix between English plus Hindi and Urdu, why did people use the word in Kenya if they had their own words like *bwana* to refer to a boss, for example? Did they really use it, and was it common in other countries?

Comment: I learned the word from reading, and I imagine most readers outside India will recognize it as a term from the British Raj. But I've never heard anybody use it in conversation, and my sense of what it means is nowhere near as detailed as what you describe.

Comment: There was a significant [Indian population in Kenya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indians_in_Kenya) at the time of the British empire and subsequently, which seems a likely reason if indeed it was used.

Comment: Mem-sahib was also used in the UK as a humorous reference to one's wife. It was also common in Tanganyika, and Uganda, as well as other parts of the British Commonwealth and influence in Asia. *Burmese Days* (George Orwell) has "The position for which Nature had designed her from the first, that of a burra memsahib."

Comment: Irish perspective : I vaguely recognise that word from some old movies about India and the British Raj, but like @JohnLawler I’ve never heard anyone use it in conversation. I don’t think many people here are familiar with it.

Comment: ***Memsahib** was used to refer to or address White women in India, especially during the period of British rule, or sometimes to refer to or address upper-class Indian women.
[old-fashioned]*. (Collins)

Comment: ***Memsahib**
in American English - 

lady; madam
a title used in colonial India by a servant, etc. in speaking to or of a European woman*. (Collins)

Comment: ***Memsahib** in British English (formerly in India) a term of respect used of a European married woman*. (Collins)

Comment: I can remember a term similar to that being used in movies in the 60s.

Comment: "There is, however, a microscopic development I have noticed lately. Whereas the servants used to address employers with the subservient “sahib” and “memsahib”, now they call them uncle and aunty". https://thewire.in/labour/people-consideration-serve-us [memsahib and sahib]

Comment: Some British men referred to their wives as “the Mensahib”, including men who had not lived in India.

Comment: @Stuart Not only a significant Indian population but also a significant population of British Indian white people, some of whom would have been born in India. These people would have virtually re-created British India in East Africa which is why the Indians were there.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the above, the term isn't just a relic of the Raj. It's still used in India, and quite commonly at that, to refer to a female superior. It's usually pronounced "Mem-Saab", literally Madam-Sir. A female Sir, if you will.

It's a sort of title as well as a form of address. A man might refer to his wife by that term when speaking to the domestic help. *Can you take this to Mem Saab please?*

Comment: But is it a term used outside India? That is what the question is asking.

Comment: In places with a significant Indian population, quite possibly.

Comment: You should add some examples of usage outside India if you can find any. Also, [sahib](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sahib#English) seems to come from Arabic *ṣaḥiba*, "to accompany" and would therefore be unrelated to "sir" (even if used similarly).

Comment: Perhaps Sahib does come from Arabic but in north India, it's just the vernacular equivalent of Sir.

Answer (score 0):

It was rarely used outside the Indian subcontinent unless used by workers enslaved by the British from Indian subcontinent. It is one of the words which was carried on by people who worked for, or were enslaved, by the British in the Indian subcontinent (including Afghanistan.)
In my opinion, the word **"mem"** has its roots in the word **"ma'am"** and was later transformed into **"memsahib."**
However, as it probably originates from old (Hindi/Urdu/Pashto), it is really hard to pinpoint.

Comment: Your answer would be better as a comment as it does not address the question. That said, the OED agrees with your suggested origin: *Etymology: < mem, variant of ma'am n.1  + sahib n. (as postmodifying title).* It is first recorded in 1832.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and the suggestion!